# change launcher activity after crash in telegram source

Tags: java, android, android-manifest, telegram

i am using telegram source and i have change the launcher activity with this code in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
        android:name="org.telegram.memberbegir.ActivitySplash"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.MULTIWINDOW_LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

But when occur a crash in application, the launcher activity changed to another activity that defined this way

```
<activity
        android:name="org.telegram.ui.LaunchActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="@bool/useHardwareAcceleration"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"></activity>
```

how can i solve this problem?

Comment: paste crash stack trace please ; )

Comment: its not depends to the crash, after any crash, for one time, the launcher activity change to "org.telegram.ui.LaunchActivity" (sorry for my bad english) @Klawikowski

Comment: please check my answer : )

Answer (score 1):

Ok as far I understand, you'd like to start specified activity after crash occurs.

1st step
Implement your own Exception Handler then set it onCreate in Application class or in Activity (I dont know how your app arch looks like):

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new ExceptionHandler(this));
```

2nd step
Do the magic inside Exception Handler. For example:

```
public class ExceptionHandler implements
    java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {
private final Context myContext;

public ExceptionHandler(Context context) {
    myContext = context;
}

public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable exception) {
    ...
    Intent intent = new Intent(myContext, AnotherActivity.class);
    //you can add intent flags like Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP to clear the activity stack etc
    myContext.startActivity(intent);


}
```

}

How does it work? Each time you will get crash, your handler will catch it, and do the job. I hope thats what you were looking for.

Comment: no i am not looking for this, i am using telegram source (is available on github), i change the project launcher activity, but when the application crash, and i open the app, i see another activity (after crash dont show my launcher activity), and i use your code to change that activity but not worked